# How can I send an Image as a signature in a mail using PHPmailer?

Tags: php

I would like to send an Image as a mail signature in the bottom of the mail using **phpmailer**. How can I do it? I used `$mail->AddEmbeddedImage("assets/img/logo.png", 100, 'logo.png');` and another some method. However my any code is not working. Please give me some advice .

Comment: Its shown me as like as attachment file.

Comment: You should post every piece of relevant code. Starting from the object construction, up to the send command. Leave out the full message please, we're not interested in your love letters ;)

Comment: you should use `cid:...` for inline attachment and place `cid` in mail body